# JMeter - "Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate "

Tags: https, jmeter

I am entering my user id and password for a https site that i am trying to record using JMeter's test script recorder element. On entering my user id and password, I get an error. When looking into the logs, I see the below error.

"Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate for XX.XX:443".

I have added the certificate in the browser. I am only having issues with a specific website alone and any other https website seem to be working fine.

I am using JMeter version 5.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you.
John

Tried importing new certificate
Tried Java,Httpclient4 type to record the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authorize JMeter certificate to browser which you are using. If so, go through this steps and look if you missed something:

1. Press Start record in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#script-recorder).
   You should get this message:
   [image]
2. Start Firefox
3. Open Firefox Menu
4. Go to "Options"
5. Go to "Privacy & Security"
6. Click "View Cerificates"
7. Ensure there are no certificates with names `"_DO NOT INSTALL.."`, `"DO NOT INSTALL.."`, 
   `"JMETER.."` and other related to JMeter cerificates, or Delete them if they are present.
8. Click "Import" to add new certificate.
9. Navigate to your JMeter bin directory and choose `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file.
10. **Check Trust this CA to identify websites.**
    [image]
11. Press Ok.
12. Do actions with your web application to record requests.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the following steps using Firefox and am getting the following error message 
" 2019-01-31 19:16:08,648 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2019-01-31 19:16:08,648 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2019-01-31 19:16:08,648 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8888
2019-01-31 19:16:08,648 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2019-01-31 19:16:33,675 WARN o.a.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator: Malformed challenge: Out of sequence NTLM response message

Comment: Add The HTTP Authorization Manager to your Login step, and set its parameters:
Username - windows domain login
Password - windows domain password
Domain - your windows domain

Comment: thank you. But I am getting this error during recording of the use cases. So would i have ability to add that before i record it ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably something is wrong with your browser configuration, i.e. old JMeter certificate is present somewhere in the certificates storage. Few things to consider:

1. [Clear your browsing history](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000510.htm).
2. Consider using a browser which has separate proxy and certificates configuration, for example [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
3. Delete `proxyserver.jks` and `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` files from the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. The files will be regenerated next time you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
4. Import the newly generated `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file into the browser

Be aware that as of now certificate lifetime is limited to 7 days so you will have to regenerate it and reimport prior to using again for recording. The certificate life span is controllable via [`proxy.cert.validity` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test script: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you will not have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. I am currenlty getting the following error message - "HttpAuthenticator: Malformed challenge: Out of sequence NTLM response message"